# How do I obtain predictions and probabilities from new data input to a CNN in Tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I'll preface this by saying this is my first posted question on SO.  I've just recently started working with Tensorflow, and have been attempting to apply a convolutional-neural network model approach for classification of .csv records in a file representing images from scans of microarray data. (FYI: Microarrays are a grid of spotted DNA on a glass slide, representing specific DNA target sequences for determining the presence of those DNA targets in a sample.  The individual pixels represent fluorescence intensity value from 0-1).   The file has ~200,000 records in total. Each record (image) has 10816 pixels that represent DNA sequences from known viruses, and one index label which identifies the virus species. The pixels create a pattern which is unique to each of the different viruses. There are 2165 different viruses in total represented within the 200,000 records. I have trained the network on images of labeled microarray datasets, but when I try to pass a new dataset through to classify it/them as one of the 2165 different viruses and determine predicted values and probabilities, I don't seem to be having much luck.  This is the code that I am currently using for this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import csv

def extract_data(filename):
    print("extracting data...")
    NUM_LABELS = 2165 
    NUM_FEATURES = 10816
    labels = []
    fvecs = []
    rowCount = 0

#iterate over the rows, split the label from the features
#convert the labels to integers and features to floats

    for line in open(filename):
        rowCount = rowCount + 1
        row = line.split(',')
        labels.append(row[3])#(int(row[7])) #<<<IT ALWAYS PREDICTS THIS VALUE!
        for x in row [4:10820]:
            fvecs.append(float(x))

#convert the array of float arrasy into a numpy float matrix
    fvecs_np = np.matrix(fvecs).astype(np.float32)

#convert the array of int lables inta a numpy array
    labels_np = np.array(labels).astype(dtype=np.uint8)

#convert the int numpy array into a one-hot matrix
    labels_onehot = (np.arange(NUM_LABELS) == labels_np[:, None]).astype(np.float32)
    print("arrays converted")
    return fvecs_np, labels_onehot

def TestModels():
    fvecs_np, labels_onehot = extract_data("MicroarrayTestData.csv")
    print('RESTORING NN MODEL')
    weights = {}
    biases = {}
    sess=tf.Session()  
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    #Load meta graph and restore weights

    ModelID = "MicroarrayCNN_Data-1000.meta" 
    print("RESTORING:::", ModelID)
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(ModelID)
    saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))

    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    x = graph.get_tensor_by_name("x:0")
    y = graph.get_tensor_by_name("y:0")
    keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32) 
    y_ = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, 2165])

    wc1 = graph.get_tensor_by_name("wc1:0")
    wc2 = graph.get_tensor_by_name("wc2:0")
    wd1 = graph.get_tensor_by_name("wd1:0")
    Wout = graph.get_tensor_by_name("Wout:0")
    bc1 = graph.get_tensor_by_name("bc1:0")
    bc2 = graph.get_tensor_by_name("bc2:0")
    bd1 = graph.get_tensor_by_name("bd1:0")
    Bout = graph.get_tensor_by_name("Bout:0")

    weights = {wc1, wc2, wd1, Wout}
    biases = {bc1, bc2, bd1, Bout}

    print("NEXTArgmax") 
    prediction=tf.argmax(y,1)
    probabilities = y
    predY = prediction.eval(feed_dict={x: fvecs_np, y: labels_onehot}, session=sess)
    probY = probabilities.eval(feed_dict={x: fvecs_np, y: labels_onehot},  session=sess)

    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(prediction, "float"))
    print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: fvecs_np, y: labels_onehot}))
    print("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%")
    print("Predicted::: ", predY, accuracy)
    print("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%")

    feed_dictTEST = {y: labels_onehot}
    probabilities=probY
    print("probabilities", probabilities.eval(feed_dict={x: fvecs_np}, session=sess))    

########## Run Analysis ###########
TestModels()
```

So, when I run this code I get the correct prediction for the test set, although I am not sure I believe it, because it appears that whatever value I append in line 14 (see below) is the output it predicts:

```
labels.append(row[3])#<<<IT ALWAYS PREDICTS THIS VALUE!
```

I don't understand this, and it makes me suspicious that I've set up the CNN incorrectly, as I would have expected it to ignore my input label and determine a bast match from the trained network based on the trained patterns.  The only thing I can figure is that when I pass the value through for the prediction; it is instead training the model on this data as well, and then predicting itself.  Is this a correct assumption, or am I misinterpreting how Tensorflow works?

The other issue is that when I try to use code that (based on other tutorials) which is supposed to output the probabilities of all of the 2165 possible outputs, I get the error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Shape [-1,2165] has negative     dimensions
[[Node: y = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,2165], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

To me, it looks like it is the correct layer based on the 2165 value in the Tensor shape, but I don't understand the -1 value.  So, to wrap up the summary, my questions are:

1. Based on the fact that I get the value that I have in the label of the input data, is this the correct method to make a classification using this model?
2. Am I missing a layer or have I configured the model incorrectly in order to extract the probabilities of all of the possible output classes, or am I using the wrong code to extract the information?  I try to print out the accuracy to see if that would work, but instead it outputs the description of a tensor, so clearly that is incorrect as well.

(ADDITIONAL INFORMATION)

As requested, I'm also including the original code that was used to train the model, which is now below.  You can see I do sort of a piece meal training of a limited number of related records at a time by their taxonomic relationships as I iterate through the file.  This is mostly because the Mac that I'm training on (Mac Pro w/ 64GB ram) tends to give me the "Killed -9" error due to overuse of resources if I don't do it this way.  There may be a better way to do it, but this seems to work.

```
Original Author: Aymeric Damien
Project: https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/

from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import csv
import random

# Parameters

num_epochs = 2
train_size = 1609
learning_rate = 0.001  #(larger >speed, lower >accuracy)
training_iters = 5000 # How much do you want to train (more = better trained)
batch_size = 32   #How many samples to train on, size of the training batch
display_step = 10 # How often to diplay what is going on during training

# Network Parameters
n_input = 10816 # MNIST data input (img shape: 28*28)...in my case 104x104 = 10816(rough array size)
n_classes = 2165 #3280 #2307 #787# Switched to 100 taxa/training set, dynamic was too wonky. 
dropout = 0.75 # Dropout, probability to keep units.  Jeffery Hinton's group developed it, that prevents overfitting to find new paths.  More generalized model. 

# Functions

def extract_data(filename):
    print("extracting data...")
    # arrays to hold the labels and feature vectors.
    NUM_LABELS = 2165 
    NUM_FEATURES = 10826

    taxCount = 0
    taxCurrent = 0

    labels = []
    fvecs = []
    rowCount = 0

    #iterate over the rows, split the label from the features
    #convert the labels to integers and features to floats
    print("entering CNN loop")
    for line in open(filename):

        rowCount = rowCount + 1
        row = line.split(',')

        taxCurrent = row[3]
        print("profile:", row[0:12])
        labels.append(int(row[3]))
        fvecs.append([float(x) for x in row [4:10820]])

    #convert the array of float arrasy into a numpy float matrix
    fvecs_np = np.matrix(fvecs).astype(np.float32)
    #convert the array of int lables inta a numpy array
    labels_np = np.array(labels).astype(dtype=np.uint8)
    #convert the int numpy array into a one-hot matrix
    labels_onehot = (np.arange(NUM_LABELS) == labels_np[:, None]).astype(np.float32)
    print("arrays converted")
    return fvecs_np, labels_onehot

# Create some wrappers for simplicity
def conv2d(x, W, b, strides=1): #Layer 1 : Convolutional layer
    # Conv2D wrapper, with bias and relu activation
    print("conv2d")
    x = tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, strides, strides, 1], padding='SAME') # Strides are the tensors...list of integers.  Tensors=data
    x = tf.nn.bias_add(x, b)  #bias is the tuning knob
    return tf.nn.relu(x) #rectified linear unit (activation function)

def maxpool2d(x, k=2): #Layer 2 : Takes samples from the image. (This is a 4D tensor)
    print("maxpool2d")
    # MaxPool2D wrapper
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, k, k, 1], strides=[1, k, k, 1],
                          padding='SAME')

# Create model
def conv_net(x, weights, biases, dropout):
    print("conv_net setup")
    # Reshape input picture
    x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 104, 104, 1])  #-->52x52 , -->26x26x64

    # Convolution Layer
    conv1 = conv2d(x, weights['wc1'], biases['bc1']) #defined above already
    # Max Pooling (down-sampling)
    conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1, k=2)
    print(conv1.get_shape)

    # Convolution Layer
    conv2 = conv2d(conv1, weights['wc2'], biases['bc2'])  #wc2 and bc2 are just placeholders...could actually skip this layer...maybe
    # Max Pooling (down-sampling)
    conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2, k=2)
    print(conv2.get_shape)

    # Fully connected layer
    # Reshape conv2 output to fit fully connected layer input
    fc1 = tf.reshape(conv2, [-1, weights['wd1'].get_shape().as_list()[0]])
    fc1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['wd1']), biases['bd1'])
    fc1 = tf.nn.relu(fc1) #activation function for the NN
    # Apply Dropout
    fc1 = tf.nn.dropout(fc1, dropout)

    # Output, class prediction
    out = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['Wout']), biases['Bout'])
    return out

def Train_Network(Txid_IN, Sess_File_Name):

    import tensorflow as tf
    tf.reset_default_graph()

    x,y = 0,0
    weights = {}
    biases = {}

    # tf Graph input
    print("setting placeholders")
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_input], name="x")  #Gateway for data (images)
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_classes], name="y") # Gateway for data (labels)
    keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32) #dropout # Gateway for dropout(keep probability)

    # Store layers weight & bias
    #CREATE weights

    weights = {
        # 5x5 conv, 1 input, 32 outputs
        'wc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 1, 32]),name="wc1"), #
        # 5x5 conv, 32 inputs, 64 outputs
        'wc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 32, 64]),name="wc2"),
        # fully connected, 7*7*64 inputs, 1024 outputs
        'wd1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([26*26*64, 1024]),name="wd1"),
        # 1024 inputs, 10 outputs (class prediction)
        'Wout': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, n_classes]),name="Wout")
    }

    biases = {
        'bc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32]), name="bc1"),
        'bc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64]), name="bc2"),
        'bd1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024]), name="bd1"),
        'Bout': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]), name="Bout")
    }

    # Construct model
    print("constructing model")
    pred = conv_net(x, weights, biases, keep_prob)

    print(pred)

    # Define loss(cost) and optimizer
    #cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred, y)) Deprecated version of the statement
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = pred, labels=y)) #added reduce_mean 6/27

    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

    # Evaluate model
    correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

    print("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%")
    print ("%%   ", correct_pred)
    print ("%%   ", accuracy)
    print("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%")

    # Initializing the variables
    #init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    saver = tf.train.Saver()

    fvecs_np, labels_onehot = extract_data("MicroarrayDataOUT.csv")  #CHAGE TO PICORNAVIRUS!!!!!AHHHHHH!!!
    print("starting session")
    # Launch the graph
    FitStep = 0
    with tf.Session() as sess:  #graph is encapsulated by its session
        sess.run(init)
        step = 1
        # Keep training until reach max iterations (training_iters)
        while step * batch_size < training_iters:
            if FitStep >= 5:
                break
            else:
                #iterate and train
                print(step)
                print(fvecs_np, labels_onehot)
                for step in range(num_epochs * train_size // batch_size):
                    sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: fvecs_np, y: labels_onehot, keep_prob:dropout})  #no dropout???...added Keep_prob:dropout
                    if FitStep >= 5:
                        break
                    #else:
                ###batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
                # Run optimization op (backprop)
                ###sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y,
                ###                               keep_prob: dropout})          <<<<SOMETHING IS WRONG IN HERE?!!!
                    if step % display_step == 0:
                        # Calculate batch loss and accuracy
                            loss, acc = sess.run([cost, accuracy], feed_dict={x: fvecs_np,
                                                                          y: labels_onehot,
                                                                          keep_prob: 1.})

                            print("Iter " + str(step*batch_size) + ", Minibatch Loss= " + \
                              "{:.6f}".format(np.mean(loss)) + ", Training Accuracy= " + \
                              "{:.5f}".format(acc))
                            TrainAcc = float("{:.5f}".format(acc))
                            #print("******", TrainAcc)
                            if TrainAcc >= .99: #Changed from .95 temporarily
                                print(FitStep)
                                FitStep = FitStep+1
                            saver.save(sess, Sess_File_Name, global_step=1000) #
                            print("Saved Session:", Sess_File_Name)
                    step += 1
        print("Optimization Finished!")

        print("Testing Accuracy:", \
            sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: fvecs_np[:256],
                                          y: labels_onehot[:256],
                                          keep_prob: 1.}))

        #feed_dictTEST = {x: fvecs_np[50]}
        #prediction=tf.argmax(y,1)
        #print(prediction)
        #best = sess.run([prediction],feed_dictTEST)
        #print(best)
        print("DONE")

    sess.close()


def Tax_Iterator(CSV_inFile, CSV_outFile): #Deprecate

    #Need to copy *.csv file to MySQL for sorting

    resultFileINIT = open(CSV_outFile,'w') 
    resultFileINIT.close()

    TaxCount = 0
    TaxThreshold = 2165
    ThresholdStep = 2165
    PrevTax = 0
    linecounter = 0
    #Open all GenBank profile list
    for line in open(CSV_inFile):
        linecounter = linecounter+1
        print(linecounter)
        resultFile = open(CSV_outFile,'a') 
        wr = csv.writer(resultFile, dialect='excel')

        # Check for new TXID
        row = line.split(',')
        print(row[7], "===", PrevTax)
        if row[7] != PrevTax:
            print("X1")
            TaxCount = TaxCount+1
            PrevTax = row[7]

        #Check it current Tax count is < or > threshold
            # < threshold
        print(TaxCount,"=+=", TaxThreshold)
        if TaxCount<=3300:
            print("X2")

            CurrentTax= row[7]

            CurrTxCount = CurrentTax  

            print("TaxCount=", TaxCount)
            print( "Add to CSV")
            print("row:", CurrentTax, "***", row[0:15])

            wr.writerow(row[0:-1])

           # is > threshold
        else:
            print("X3")
            # but same TXID....
            print(row[7], "=-=", CurrentTax)
            if row[7]==CurrentTax:
                print("X4")
                CurrentTax= row[7]
                print("TaxCount=", TaxCount)
                print( "Add to CSV")
                print("row:", CurrentTax, "***", row[0:15])

                wr.writerow(row[0:-1])

            # but different TXID...
            else:

                print(row[7], "=*=", CurrentTax)
                if row[7]>CurrentTax:
                    print("X5")
                    TaxThreshold=TaxThreshold+ThresholdStep
                    resultFile.close()

                    Sess_File_Name = "CNN_VirusIDvSPECIES_XXALL"+ str(TaxThreshold-ThresholdStep)
                    print("<<<< Start Training >>>>"
                    print("Training on :: ", CurrTxCount, "Taxa", TaxCount, "data points.")

                    Train_Network(CurrTxCount, Sess_File_Name)
                    print("Training complete")
                    resultFileINIT = open(CSV_outFile,'w') 
                    resultFileINIT.close()
                    CurrentTax= row[7]

                    #reset tax count

                    CurrTxCount = 0
                    TaxCount = 0
    resultFile.close()

    Sess_File_Name = "MicroarrayCNN_Data"+ str(TaxThreshold+ThresholdStep)
    print("<<<< Start Training >>>>")

    print("Training on :: ", CurrTxCount, "Taxa", TaxCount, "data points.")
    Train_Network(CurrTxCount, Sess_File_Name)
    resultFileINIT = open(CSV_outFile,'w') 
    resultFileINIT.close()
    CurrentTax= row[7]   


Tax_Iterator("MicroarrayInput.csv", "MicroarrayOutput.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined prediction as `prediction=tf.argmax(y,1)`. And in both `feed_dict`, you feed `labels_onehot` for `y`. Consequently, your "prediction" is always equal to the labels.

As you didn't post the code you used to train your network, I can't tell you what exactly you need to change.

Edit: I have isses understanding the underlying problem you're trying to solve - based on your code, you're trying to train a neural network with 2165 different classes using 1609 training examples. How is this even possible? If each example had a different class, there would still be some classes without any training example. Or does one image belong to many classes? From your statement at the beginning of your question, I had assumed you're trying to output a real-valued number between 0-1.

I'm actually surprised that the code actually worked as it looks like you're adding only a single number to your `labels` list, but your model expects a list with length `2165` for each training example.

Comment: Thank you for looking at this.  I have posted the additional script for the original training of the CNN.  It was downloaded from a tutorial which I then attempted to hack for my own use.

Comment: @RWBarrette I have updated my answer, didn't quite fit into a comment, sorry

Comment: So, let me try to reframe the question with more info.  I have a file of ~200,000 records in total.  Each record (image) has 10816 pixels that represent DNA sequences from known viruses, and one index label which identifies the virus species.  The pixels create a pattern which is unique to each of the different viruses.  There are 2165 different viruses in total represented within the 200,000 records.  The computer can't seem to handle this much input at once, so, I am parsing through the file and piecemeal training it on a few species at a time.

Comment: Once the subset of data that it is training on iterates through 5X at >99% accuracy, it moves onto the next subset of viruses.  So at each iteration, there is not a full representation of the possible outputs, but over the entire ~200,000 records, all should be represented.  Is Tensorflow able to handle this sort-of interative approach to training, or am I incorrect in my assumptions?  At the end of the day, after it has trained on all of these, I use the script that reloads the trained network and try to predict the virus species based on new patterns that have not been trained upon.

Comment: However, I also want to see the probabilities of ALL of the possible viral indices when classifying new viruses, as it is always possible to have more than one virus represented in a sample.  I realize that it cannot predict more than one virus at >99% as it has never been trained on multiples, but I'm curious to see what the probability breakdowns look like when I do have more than one virus represented in an 'image', and see if there is predictive value in these comparisons.  Sorry for multiple comments, but I  figure the details may be useful in understanding the method to my madness.

Comment: I was under the impression that I was setting up the network to train for 1 of 2165 possible outcomes, but based on your comment am I to understand that I've actually set it up to expect 2165 labels associated with each of the 10816 pixels?

Comment: I also updated the original post to reflect some of this.  Also, I modified the statement regarding the fluorescence which (as you pointed out) was confusing and made it seem like the CNN was trying to predict the fluorescence value.  Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: I think I understand it now - let me try to rephrase it. You have 200,000 104x104 images representing the DNA sequence of viruses. Each image corresponds to one of 2,165 classes (each class representing a single virus). And what you were trying to do is train the network using ALL images from class 1, after that class 2, then class 3, etc.? If yes, then this doesn't work. The network will always have a 100% accuracy then, as it only "sees" one class and will just always output that very class.

Comment: You must find a way to shuffle the data beforehand, but there are many ways to do this. As apparantly, you can't fit all 200.000 images into your RAM, you could for example load the images as you need them which however will obviously be significantly slower.

Comment: What I'd suggest you to do is focus on making sure that the network does what it is supposed to do. Use a smaller subset of your data (for example 10 classes) that fits into memory, shuffle the dataset and try training a network that is able to distinguish these 10 classes. Set aside ~10% of this data to use for testing to ensure that the network didn't overfit. Once you're satisfied with your results, you can try to use whatever approach you want to try for not loading all examples at a time and ensure that the results stay the same. And then, you can use all of your data for training.